# C# code is hanging on a call to Listview.CheckedTems.Count - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, visual-studio-2017

I've written a C# Windows form created in Visual Studio 2017.

In a button click event handler, I have a simple if statement that never completes:

> if (listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems.Count < added.Count)

listViewAddedKeys is a ListView, and "added" is a Hashtable.

This is the complete function:

```
private void buttonSaveAdded_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (saveFileDialog.FileName != String.Empty)
            {
                OnProgressEvent("Saving Data...");
                DisableControls(this.Controls);
                if (listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems.Count < added.Count)
                    HashFromSelected(ref listViewAddedKeys, ref added, out currentSaving, false);
                else
                    currentSaving = added;
                BeginSaveData.BeginInvoke(saveFileDialog.FileName, ref currentSaving,
                    OnSaveDataCallback, BeginSaveData);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OnProgressEvent("Problem in buttonSaveAdded_Click(): " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

listViewAddedKeys is a ListView, and "added" is a Hashtable.

If I break on the line:
DisableControls(this.Controls);

and add "listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems.Count" to the "Watch 1" tab of the debugger, the debugger is unable to retrieve the value (Function evaluation timed out).  If I change that to just "listViewAddedKeys" I'm able to drill down into it quite a bit (for instance, I can see that the item count is 1,478,670), however, if I continue to scroll down through it, Visual Studio crashes.

I'm not doing anything tricky with threads, and the only lock I have on anything has a breakpoint set on it which hasn't yet triggered.

I tried following the advice [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/10/16/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough/), but none of the output in windbg matches with the items they want me to look for.

CPU utilization is 0 while running at this point, and the resource manager shows that it's not doing anything to the disk, memory, or network.

This is on a Windows 10 (fully patched as of 8/30/2017) enterprise system.  The code is compiled for .NET Framework 4.6.1.  Code Analysis comes up clean.

Are there any other steps I can perform before declaring that the problem is not with my code?

Comment: Ate you facing this issue only while debugging? If you run without debugging does it work fine?

Comment: The problem happens when I execute outside of a debugger too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, if the issue is not in your code, you still want to learn enough to create a workaround, right?

Some debugging steps you could take:

1. Create temp variables for the counts and see if you can step past them outside of the if statement:

> ```
> int tmpListViewCount = listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems.Count;
> int tmpAddedCount = added.Count;
> if( tmpListViewCount < tmpAddedCount )
> { // HashFromSelected, etc.. }
> ```

2. Swap `tmpListViewCount` and `tmpAddedCount` or use some other method to run `tmpAddedCount` first.
3. Try instantiating a .CheckedItems list or extract it from `listViewAddedKeys` so it is a separate object.  Is there a way you can inspect it directly so that you can tell how many objects are in it (i.e. what the count should return with)?  Maybe through a breakpoint and mousing over?  Try the `.count` directly on that object.  Maybe create a static one that you directly set the list to (not sure what the class is for that).

> ```
> CheckedItemsClass tmpCheckedItems = listViewAddedKeys.CheckItems; 
> int tmpListViewCount = tmpCheckedItems.Count;
> int tmpAddedCount = added.Count;
> if( tmpListViewCount < tmpAddedCount )
> { // HashFromSelected, etc.. }
> ```

4. Setup the UI so that you are calling this function with a static `listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems` and `added` variable that have a defined count that you know ahead of time (1 would be nice...).  Maybe make up a button that adds 1 item to each, then call this function so if it succeeds you can manually add more.

I have a feeling the issue is with whatever "CheckedItems" is creating or how that is counted, but not sure.  When you count the Checked Items, does that add a count, making an endless loop?  Anyway, these should at least show a few debugging methods you might use to break apart and setup your debugging sessions so that you have more control over the situation.  Ideally, you know ahead of time what you expect the two counts to be before debugging - have a hypothesis of how you expect these methods to work and what they will return, then you can definitively understand where things are not meeting your expectations.  Modify exactly what you are sending into the function after that to see how it changes the response, etc.  Basically, apply the scientific method.

Comment: int tempCount = listViewAddedKeys.CheckedItems.Count; never returns.  Eventually the debugger states that an exception has been thrown:  "Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' has detected a problem in ...  : The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0x10dcd18 to COM context 0x10dcc60 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages."

Comment: ... " This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations."

Comment: So you found the rabbit hole you need to dig down into (i.e. the goal of #1 and #2 in my list).  How about #3 and #4?

Comment: For #3, I mentioned in the OP that if I attempt to investigate the object, Visual Studio crashes.  I tried this too:  ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection temp = listViewAddedKeys.CheckedITems;  If I attempt to get the count of temp, it too fails.  The count should be 1,478,670-- oddly I can get the count of all the items in the listview, it's just when I check for the Checked items that this happens.  In otherwords, no rabbit hole to dig down into.  The problem seems to be in the .net code itself.

Comment: Apparently it is possible to step into .net's source code -- I wasn't aware of this.  [How to: Debug .NET Framework Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx)  I'm going to see if I can't find out exactly what's breaking where.

Comment: Nevermind -- even that doesn't work.  F11 on int test = temp.Count; doesn't enter .net core source code, I'm still stuck waiting for the step to complete (Running).  This time however, I never get that ContextSwitchDeadlock message.

Comment: Okay, so #3 isn't working - Now try #4 - Substitute a much simpler version of the listview and see if you get the same error.  If the simple version passes, try building it up (progressively) until it is the same and see where the failure occurs.  Or go the other direction - cut the complex object in half and see if the first half of the items get counted okay, but last half fails.  Might be able to "split the dictionary" until you find a particular item (or items) that are causing the failure, etc. (note: if this answer and these comments are helpful, would appreciate upvotes on them)

Comment: I put a break in the loop that populated the list so that only one entry was added. The code works fine now... I wonder if I'm running into an upper limit...  I'm going to arbitrarily break out of the loop with larger and larger number of entries until I find when the code breaks again -- however even if it does break at some # -- I'm not sure how to proceed -- I need everything in the one listview.

Comment: At 500,000 entries, it never returns... I've got it working up to 100,000 so far.

Comment: So my question is still the same -- I'm already aware of breaking down a problem into smaller pieces; that's troubleshooting 101.  The problem I'm experiencing exists in code I don't have control over (.net framework) and thus cannot break down further.  I was hoping for advice debugging the .net framework itself, or otherwise using visual studio to reveal more details about why this call doesn't complete (say, tricks to reveal thread information, possible locks, resource limits, etc). The closest I came to answer was that link I found to debug the source of the .net framework.

Comment: Can you implement a workaround by implementing your own version of .count for this particular object?   I'm in the same boat as you on more detailed debugging of a library itself (including .NET).  Note it could be a particular item you are adding, rather than the total count (i.e. something has a special character causing the failure, etc.).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how, but I believe it would require writing my own control.  I've done more testing -- as the count increases, the time it takes to process increases exponentially.  300,000 takes 9:31 minutes.  500,000 takes 26:56 minutes.  So the control is working, just taking forever for the million+ entries I've got (I had let it run for two days without it returning).

Comment: Okay, I think I've answered your original question, we are on to at least question 2 now...  I think you need a follow-up question, providing more information about the ListViewItems and why you have 1.5M items in a list view that are checked, to get help with the technical direction here. My initial guess is you are jamming some data into a UI control that should be handled behind the scenes in a different format, especially if your listview items are highly complex, but again, that is a separate Q&A - we have implemented testing methods that have isolated at least where the failure is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll go ahead and give you answer credit.  I've started a new question about this particular performance problem.